# Allow members to only see their own trips in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, crud

I have an app where members can create trips, but I need to limit access so that only the user that created their trip can see it, but it's not working as anticipated. I'm using the devise gem, so current_member is equivalent to @member or @suer.

This is the 'show' page for the trip:

```
<% if current_member.id == params[:member_id] %>
    <h1>Here are your current trips </h1>
    <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
      <%= link_to trip.where, member_trip_path(current_member.id, trip.id) %><br>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <h1>Sorry, this page isn't available.</h1>
<% end %>
```

This is the path:

```
member_trip GET    /members/:member_id/trips/:id(.:format)      trips#show
```

What I'm expecting is that if I have two member's: bob and susan. Susan can't see bob's trip show page by just typing the trip id in the url. She should see "Sorry, this page isn't available" on the page.

Comment: Where do you get the `@trips` from?

Comment: @Hotconnection As you are new to SO, I would like to suggest you that being a good learner and contributor, you should accept the answer which solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

You need model associations.

Your `members.rb` model should have `has_many :trips` and `trip.rb` model should have `belongs_to :member`. You will need to have `member_id` column in your `trips` table.

In your controller, you will need to write:

```
@trips = current_member.trips # it will return trips created by the current member only.
```

You can read more about the `has_many` association [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) and the `belongs_to` association [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).